# SELECT mulitple parameters on mySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to learn to use mySQL by going through the [W3's tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp).  I was reading about the SQL BETWEEN operator and how it allows you to select values within a range.  I was following the [tutorial example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_between_text):

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE ProductName BETWEEN 'C' AND 'M';
```

and thought it would be cool if you could also sort by ProductName in Ascending order. I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE ProductName BETWEEN 'C' AND 'M' AND OrderBY ASC;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE ProductName BETWEEN 'C' AND 'M';
AND OrderBY ASC;
```

as well as

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE ProductName BETWEEN 'C' AND 'M', OrderBY ASC;
```

Each one gives an error:

```
'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression'
```

But I'm not sure of the proper syntax when using multiple parameters. More generally I was wondering if an SQL query can have multiple parameters. i.e.  Select this table and sort according to parameter one, and parameter two or if you would need to create a separate query for each action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductName BETWEEN 'C' AND 'M'  -- no comma/semicolon after [WHERE] clause
ORDER BY ProductName ASC;              -- ORDER BY colName..
```

Comment: So when creating a query you don't need to separate parameters by a column, just put the query on the next line and close with a semi-colon?

Comment: @strasbal: It has nothing to do with *the next line* or a *semicolon*. It has to do with sorting being an actual separate clause. You don't use AND to ORDER BY. Read your attempts, and then read Gordon's again and compare them.

Comment: @KenWhite just wanted to make sure that a separate clause didn't need to be separated by being on the next line or with a semi-colon.  I got it now, thanks!

Comment: @strasbal You might want to mark his answer as the correct answer (below up and down votes) so the question is marked as solved.